# Cannot see folder in windows 10 after locking by third-party

Tags: windows-10

A week ago, I used a third-party software to hide my folder. This is the software: https://www.lock-folder.com/
I installed the software on partition C, but I used it to hide a folder on partition D.
Some days later, I formated partition C to reinstall Windows 10, now I cannot see the folder that was hidden before on partion D. How can I make it visible?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Since you presumably know the names of the folder.  You can manually navigate to the folder.  If you encrypted the files, then you have made it impossible, to decrypt the files.  Restoring your files from a backup is your only option.

Comment: But the folder is unreachable even if I manually navigate to it...

Comment: Then you are out of luck.  You have put yourself in a position where data recovery, due to the way the program works, is not going to be possible.  The documentation on the website indicates, if you knew the path, you should have been able to navigate to your hidden folder.

Comment: In the future, you should seriously consider utilizing the built-in Windows capability to [make a hidden folder](https://www.howtogeek.com/104825/make-a-super-hidden-folder-in-windows-without-any-extra-software/) and lock it down with NTFS permissions.  Third-party software is unnecessary and (as you have seen) potentially problematic.